# How NotificationCenter#addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:) works?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a notification posted in the main thread, and I want to exec something in the background after I receiving that notification.

So I use this method with a background `OperationQueue`

```swift
func addObserver(forName name: NSNotification.Name?, 
          object obj: Any?, 
           queue: OperationQueue?, 
           using block: @escaping (Notification) -> Void) -> NSObjectProtocol
```

I thought this should work, but it doesn't.

I have read about the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver), there are something I don't understand about the queue, it says:

```
queue
The operation queue to which block should be added.

If you pass nil, the block is run synchronously on the posting thread.
```

so if we pass nil, the block will run **synchronously** on the posting thread, but what about if we pass a `queue`, does it still run **synchronously** on the posting thread?

I have wrote some code to test my thinking,

```swift
import Foundation

let queue = OperationQueue()
let testNotification = Notification.Name("testNotification")

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: testNotification, object: nil, queue: queue) { _ in
    print("receive notification: before sleep.")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("receive notification: after sleep.")
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: testNotification, object: nil)

print("main thread")
RunLoop.main.run()
```

the output was:

```
receive notification: before sleep.
receive notification: after sleep.
main thread
```

so the block does run **synchronously** on the posting thread.

My question was, what's the point of this method, and what's the point of the params `queue`, when should we use it?

Answer (score 4):

I added:

```swift
import Foundation

let queue = OperationQueue()
let testNotification = Notification.Name("testNotification")

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: testNotification, object: nil,
                                       queue: queue) { _ in

    if queue == OperationQueue.current { print("I am in my queue") }

    print("receive notification: before sleep.")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("receive notification: after sleep.")
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: testNotification, object: nil)

print("main thread")
```

This prints out:

```
I am in my queue
receive notification: before sleep.
receive notification: after sleep.
main thread
```

We can tell it is running the `using` block in the [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) `queue`.

My understanding is the `NotificationCenter.post` method will wait until the `using` block is complete (**synchronously**) regardless of what queue it runs the `using` block in. There is a [NotificationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationqueue) buffer class that gives the functionality you are looking for.

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: testNotification, object: nil,
                                       queue: queue) { _ in

    print("receive notification: before sleep.")
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
    print("receive notification: after sleep.")
}

NotificationQueue.default.enqueue(Notification(name: testNotification),
                                  postingStyle: .whenIdle)

print("main thread")
```

Prints out:

```
main thread
receive notification: before sleep.
receive notification: after sleep.
```

I think the reason for the `queue` parameter is if using a **serial** queue for access control, one could pass in the `queue` to use. For example the UIKit uses the `main` queue to serialize all screen manipulation.You could do something like

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: testNotification, object: nil,
                                       queue: OperationQueue.main) { _ in
    // Do a bunch of UI stuff
}
```

So when you update your model from a background queue, you can post a notification to the controller to update the views, and guarantee the UIKit manipulation is done in the `main` queue.